# Count lines inside a pandas data frame group with agg()

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new in this community and in python programming, sorry for any dummy question :-)
I have created a data frame based on a dictionary as follows:

```
ContinentDict  = {'China':'Asia', 
                  'United States':'North America', 
                  'Japan':'Asia', 
                  'United Kingdom':'Europe', 
                  'Russian Federation':'Europe', 
                  'Canada':'North America', 
                  'Germany':'Europe', 
                  'India':'Asia',
                  'France':'Europe', 
                  'South Korea':'Asia', 
                  'Italy':'Europe', 
                  'Spain':'Europe', 
                  'Iran':'Asia',
                  'Australia':'Australia', 
                  'Brazil':'South America'}
df=pd.DataFrame(list(ContinentDict.items()),columns=['Country','Continent'])
```

I want to count how many countries there are in each continent by grouping and aggregating.
My first solution worked:

```
ans1=pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('Continent')['Country'].count())
```

But I would like to use aggregation. What is wrong with this?

```
ans2=df.groupby('Continent').agg({'Country':count})
```

Comment: In ans2, you need to put count in quotes. like this:  `df.groupby('Continent').agg({'Country':'count'})`

Comment: Hi thanks, it worked! But I do not understand why in this case I should pass the function inside quotation marks and in other cases, for example to aggregate the sum of values in a column, I must pass the function as np.sum, without quotation marks. What is the difference in both cases?

Comment: pandas has some strings that map to various functions: 'sum', 'mean', 'count' and a few others.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have problems trying to aggregate an index. You can do it this way:

```
df = pd.Series(ContinentDict).reset_index()
df.columns = ['country','continent']
df.groupby('continent')['country'].size()
```

Comment: Hi, you are right! It is necessary to reset the index. I have corrected in the question, thanks.